# Create additional dataframes on the basis of existing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have small market products sales data in Pandas dateframe:

```
date     product  name    turnover  qty   receipts_qty  profit  

2015-42  2889220  milk    17.73     3.000       3       13.2700  
2015-42  2905772  bread   40.94     2.000       2       40.9400 
2015-42  2876012  salt    291.36    5.000       3       292.2450  
2015-42  2846814  cakes   92.43     4.000       4       55.5300
...
2015-46  2889220  milk    12.44     2.000       2       9.9344
2015-46  2905772  bread   62.11     3.000       3       62.1100 
2015-42  2876012  salt    210.76    4.000       3       190.0050  
2015-42  2846814  cakes   120.27    5.000       4       72.1300


[14934 rows x 7 columns]
```

What I'm need is to get additional two dataframes based on 'qty' column between start and end dates - one for products that have grown on sales and second for products that have fallen in sales. Something like this:

```
Increase
name    qty_change  profit_change

bread   1.000       21.2700
cakes   1.000       16.6000
...

Decrease
name    qty_change  profit_change

milk    -1.000      -3,3356
salt    -1.000      -102,2400
...
```

Comment: Something like `increase = df[df.groupby('name')['qty'].diff() > 0]; decrease = df.groupby('name')['qty'].diff() < 0]` could be a good starting point.

Comment: @Abdou not working: in test example of 8 rows with 4 pairs of product found only one increase (should be two) and two decrease (this ok). Also, doesn't calculate qty difference - just takes last value.

Comment: Please see the answer. It uses your sample dataset and gets your desired output. Please try it and report back.

Comment: @Abdou sorry, my fault. Your answer is right. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

products = pd.DataFrame({'product': [2889220, 2905772, 2876012, 2846814, 2889220, 2905772, 2876012, 2846814], 
    'date': ['2015-42', '2015-42', '2015-42', '2015-42', '2015-46', '2015-46', '2015-42', '2015-42'], 
    'receipts_qty': [3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4], 
    'qty': [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], 
    'profit': [13.27, 40.94, 292.245, 55.53, 9.9344, 62.11, 190.005, 72.13], 
    'name': ['milk', 'bread', 'solt', 'cackes', 'milk', 'bread', 'solt', 'cackes'], 
    'turnover': [17.73, 40.94, 291.36, 92.43, 12.44, 62.11, 210.76, 120.27]})


products[['qty_change','profit_change']] = products.groupby('name')[['qty','profit']].diff()

increase = products[products.qty_change > 0][['name','qty_change','profit_change']]
print(increase)

#     name  qty_change  profit_change
#5   bread         1.0          21.17
#7  cackes         1.0          16.60


decrease = products[products.qty_change < 0][['name','qty_change','profit_change']]

print(decrease)
#   name  qty_change  profit_change
#4  milk        -1.0        -3.3356
#6  solt        -1.0      -102.2400
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, this almost worked - doesn't calculate profit difference, I got only zeros in profit_change column.

Comment: isn't that `profit_change`? It matches your expected output.

Comment: Check your `profit` column to make sure that it is of a numeric type (i.e. that it contains numbers).

Comment: checked column type by df.profit.dtype - prints 'float64'

Comment: What do you get with `df.profit.diff()`? If you're seeing zeros all around, then it must be something with that column.